# count words and lines on SQL Lite

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, group-by

I want to count the quantity of words on each line and the total of the values for example

```
user    message
----------------------
Robert | hey how are u?
Jenn   | Im fine
Wendy  | Hi Ya
Robert | Cool
```

the result on sql should be

```
Robert 5
Jenn   2
Wendy  2
```

which is count the words on each row from the users and group in the result.

How I can do that on sql lite ?

Answer (score 1):

Count the spaces + 1

```
select `user`, sum(length(message) - length(replace(message, ' ', ''))+1) as words
from your_table
group by `user`
```